# How can I show iPhone display in Macbook or iMac i.e. on larger screen?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, imac, display

I like to read books in PDF Expert while waiting busses. When I go home, I would like to see the iPhone screen on iMac or Macbook. I have VGA -adapter but I have no external display with male-VGA so cannot use it. So how can I show iPhone display in more large screen such as Macbook or iMac?

Comment: If you have a newer iPhone and an Apple TV, you can show your iPhone display on a really large TV screen.

Comment: do you have an external display with female-VGA port?

Comment: @ShineethHamza no, I don't have. I have iMac, Macbook -- available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Quicktime screen recorder with your iPhone connected via USB and set the input in Quicktime to the iPhone screen.

https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/record-iphone-screen-quicktime/

Comment: It would be good to add to your answer on what version of macOS this work.  The original question was from 2012.  The way you mention in this answer was not possible in that version.